# How to use preceding sibling for XML with xPath in Python?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, tags, lxml

I have an XML structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pages>
    <page id="1" bbox="0.000,0.000,462.047,680.315" rotate="0">
        <textbox id="0" bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
            <textline bbox="179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510">
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">C</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="192.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">A</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="193.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">P</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum-it"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.333">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">T</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">L</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">O</text>
                <text></text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text font="NUMPTY+ImprintMTnum"  bbox="191.745,592.218,199.339,603.578" ncolour="0" size="12.482">I</text>
                <text></text>
            </textline>
        </textbox>
    </page>
</pages>
```

Attribute bbox in text tag has four values, and I need to have the difference of the first bbox value of an element and its preceding one. In other words, the distance between the first two bboxes is 1. In the following loop, I need to find the preceding sibling of the bbox attribute value I take in order to calculate the distance between the two.

```
   def wrap(line, idxList):
        if len(idxList) == 0:
            return    # No elements to wrap
        # Take the first element from the original location
        idx = idxList.pop(0)     # Index of the first element
        elem = removeByIdx(line, idx) # The indicated element
        # Create "newline" element with "elem" inside
        nElem = E.newline(elem)
        line.insert(idx, nElem)  # Put it in place of "elem"
        while len(idxList) > 0:  # Process the rest of index list
            # Value not used, but must be removed
            idxList.pop(0)
            # Remove the current element from the original location
            currElem = removeByIdx(line, idx + 1)
            nElem.append(currElem)  # Append it to "newline"

    for line in root.iter('textline'):
        idxList = []
        for elem in line:
            bbox = elem.attrib.get('bbox')
            if bbox is not None:
                tbl = bbox.split(',')
                distance = float(tbl[2]) - float(tbl[0])
            else:
                distance = 100  # "Too big" value
            if distance > 10:
                par = elem.getparent()
                idx = par.index(elem)
                idxList.append(idx)
            else:  # "Wrong" element, wrap elements "gathered" so far
                wrap(line, idxList)
                idxList = []
        # Process "good" elements without any "bad" after them, if any
        wrap(line, idxList)

    #print(etree.tostring(root, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True))
```

I tried with xPath like this:

```
for x in tree.xpath("//text[@bbox<preceding::text[1]/@bbox+11]"):
print(x)
```

But it returns nothing. Is my path wrong and how can I insert it in the loop?

Comment: Duplicate with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61213788/how-to-take-preceding-element-when-iterating-over-xml-in-python First you have to transform your XML with an XSL file in order to query with this XPath. Otherwise it wont't work.http://xsltransform.net/aBcT67/1 The XPath expression will select text nodes which respect the condition : bbox  - bbox value of the preceding text node not greater than 10. If that's really your objective of course. With your sample data, the XPath expression won't work (since no nodes respect this condition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code failed is that the axis name concerning preceding siblings
is *preceding-sibling* (not *preceding*).

But here you don't need to use *XPath* expressions, as there is native *lxml*
method to get the (first) preceding sibling called *getprevious*.

To check access to previous *text* node, try the following loop:

```
for x in tree.xpath('//text'):
    bb = x.attrib.get('bbox')
    if bb is not None:
        bb = bb.split(',')
    print('This: ', bb)
    xPrev = x.getprevious()
    bb = None
    if xPrev is not None:
        bb = xPrev.attrib.get('bbox')
        if bb is not None:
            bb = bb.split(',')
    if bb is not None:
        print('  Previous: ', bb)
    else:
        print('  No previous bbox')
```

It prints *bbox* for the current *text* element and for the
immediately preceding sibling if any.

## Edit

If you want, you can also directly access *bbox* attribute in the preceding
*text* element, calling *x.xpath('preceding-sibling::text[1]/@bbox')*.

But remember that this function returns a **list** of found nodes and if nothing
has been found, this list is **empty** (not *None*).

So before you make any use of this result, you must:

- check the length of the returned list (should be > 0),
- retrieve the first element from this list (the text content of *bbox* attribute,
  in this case this list should contain only 1 element),
- split it by `,` (getting a list of fragments),
- check whether the first element of this result is not empty,
- convert of to *float*.

After that you can use it, e.g. compare with the corresponding value from the current *bbox*.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that my XML has text tags without attributes. In this case bbox results as None and I need to have the bbox before the "None" one. How can I do it?

Comment: You wrote *text tags without attributes*, so your XML sample is probably wrong.
Correct your XML sample (show where are these text tags). Otherwise I don't
know how to deal with this case.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses the very old XPath 1.0 standard. In XPath 1.0, the "<" operator always converts its operands to numbers. So when you write

```
//text[@bbox < preceding::text[1]/@bbox + 11]
```

you are performing numeric differencing and numeric addition on `@bbox` values.

But `@bbox` is not a number, it is a comma-separated list of four numbers:

```
179.739,592.028,261.007,604.510
```

Converting that to a number produces NaN (not-a-number), and `NaN < NaN` returns false.

To do anything useful with a structured attribute value like this, you really need XPath 2.0 or later.